# USING multiple 'OR' conditions in JOIN component in Oracle data Integrator 12c

Tags: oracle, join, left-join, multiple-tables

I want to use multiple '**OR**' conditions in `JOIN` component in Oracle data Integrator 12c.

> Conditions to be taken care when doing the above task is:

1. Say table T1 and T2, I need to take left outer join on T1(i.e. I need all the records from T1 for multiple satisfied join conditions specified in JOIN component in ODI 12c)
2. For example: 
   a. For table T1, T2: say conditions c1, c2, c3. T1 **Left outer join**  T2.
   b. I want to get the data in table say T3: Ensuring all records from T1 *PLUS* all records from T2 for all the conditions satisfied(namely c1,c2,c3).
3. Sample query:
   select T1.* 
   from T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 
   ON (C1 OR C2 OR C3);

Kindly help me on this at the earliest.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with your query? What was your error?

Comment: You are not clear. What do you want? What is the point of 3? In a comment you say "in Oracle Data Integrator"--make that a tag, and explain *exactly* what you want in your question. Use more sentences. Don't just say fragments about what you want. Read & act on [mcve],

Answer (score 1):

You can try either query both will get you all the rows from T1 that either matched with T2 columns respectively or didn't have any match with T2.

Using `UNION`

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
    SELECT T1.*
    FROM T1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.day = T2.day
     UNION
    SELECT T1.* 
    FROM T1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.month = T2.month
     UNION
    SELECT T1.*
    FROM T1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.yearly = T2.yearly
   ) as T3;
```

Using `OR` (`NOTE:` displaying T2 columns just to show that LEFT JOIN is working on each condition)

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON 
(T1.day = T2.day OR T1.month = T2.month OR T1.yearly = T2.yearly)
```

Sample Run

I have 4 records in T1 and 3 records in T2. Records in T1 are such that 3 rows 
 match with exactly 1 column in T2 and 4th row doesnt match any records in T2.

Output of both the queries gets what you need.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update...I have tried this but instead can't this be achieved using table t1 and t2 only once...just a thought!

Comment: check the second query and screenshots from sqlfiddle. Single query with T1 and T2 with OR can achieve what you need.

Comment: Thank you JRG! for the update. But, I am looking for this fix how this can we achieved in Oracle Data Integrator.